# python array conditional change on elements check numpy

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, numpy

I have an array and want to change some of the elements if they are negative (could be any boolean condition), however I also want to know if my code did that.

Currently I have

```
Mat = #some source
Check = Mat < 0
Check_flag = Check.sum()

if check_flag != 0:
    Mat[Check] = 0 #reset those elements
    logger = logger + '\n This Mat needed to be fixed' #or some over logging method
```

This may be the best method, but it feels somehow too 'LBYL' to be pythonic - also I typically deal with array in excess of 1e6 elements - and then loop - so I'm a little worried about the performance implications of performing the check twice (once when the 'Check' array is created - and then again when summing up over all elements just to see if one of them was a 'true').

Does anyone know of a better (more efficient) way of doing this?

Comment: As a side note, variable names should be lowercase in python, and class name have the first letter in uppercase. It is far more easier for others to read your code if you roughly follow the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) indications.

Comment: I've generally been using capitals for the matrices (/numpy arrays) in this application - but I take your point that it's good practice to keep things consistent with agreed Standards. @J.Martinot-Lagarde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to keep the elements `>=0`, you should use np.clip:

```
np.clip(Mat, 0, np.inf, out=Mat)
```

Another way to do it more efficiently is:

```
Mat[ Mat<0 ] = 0
```

In both cases you are dropping the `if` statement, in case you have to keep it, you can use `np.any` which will return `True` if any element in `Check` has a `True` value, avoiding the sum.

```
Check = Mat<0
if np.any(Check):
    Mat[Check] = 0
    ...
```

Comment: `np.clip` is a lot faster if you want to restrict values, especially if you do it in place. You can use `np.inf` as an upper bound.

Comment: @Ophion thank you, I've just edited the answer... `np.inf` is far more elegant

Comment: I think the `np.any()` looks like what I need, as I want to do other things as well 'if and only if' I had to remove negatives.

Comment: @CastleH great... later you can compare if there will be a performance gain against your current solution... don't forget to accept the answer if you think if fits your needs ;)